# Bootstrap class container does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing some site on ASP MVC. I use Visual Studio 2017. I have installed bootstrap plugin from NUGET packages. But the following code does not work. I mean that class container does not add the margins. Why so? What i did wrong? Script which i added, embeds disqus commenting system.

```html
<div class="container text-center">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h2>@Model.Title</h2>
         <p>@Html.Raw(Model.Content)</p>
         <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
         <script>
(function () { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
   var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
   s.src = 'https://incredibleenglish.disqus.com/embed.js';
   s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
   (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
         </script>
         <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a 
            href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Just the `container` class is not working? Or any of the `row, col-md-8`?

Comment: Have you tried developer tool and inspect the `container` class ?

Comment: 'JSF Run code snippet' loads bootstrap right? @wahdan

Comment: check the network tab in the console, see the status of bbootstrap.css file. May the linking of the file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it works ,i think it has something to do with your bootstrap installation

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>@Model.Title</h2>
                <p>@Html.Raw(Model.Content)</p>
                <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
                <script>
                    (function () { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
                        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
                        s.src = 'https://incredibleenglish.disqus.com/embed.js';
                        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
                    })();
                </script>
                <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a 
                 href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by 
                 Disqus.</a></noscript>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```